# Deleting file from C:/ProgramData in Windows 7 does not really delete the file?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, filesystems, delphi-xe

I have a little problem with my application. Application stores a SQLite database in `C:\ProgramData\ProgramName\` folder on first run. I wanted to test if I delete the database, can application create a new database. On startup, I check if file exists using `FileExists(filename)` function from SysUtils. But it returns always True, even if I deleted the ProgramName folder.

If I use another folder (for example %AppData%), then it's all OK.

What I'm missing here? Why FileExists function returns always True?

Comment: Does your program have write access there? Else you might hit the redirection shim.

Comment: @CodeInChaos What is redirection shim?

Comment: Ok found my virtualized database file too at %AppData%\Local\VirtualStore\ProgramData\ProgramName folder

Comment: `C:/ProgramData/ProgramName/` path has wrong `PathDelim`, all Windows versions are using '\'. I was unable to reproduce your issue with correct path.

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light Sorry, this is my typing mistake. I'm using actually CSIDL_ values.

Comment: @evilone, OK, let me check with CSIDLs (i have similar setup at work and really curious about that FileExists mistery) BTW, which are you using to query path? Might wrong or empty location returned be an issue?

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light Wrong path is not the issue, because my database component shows correct path to the database location. I think there's not a write access problem, but maybe the redirection shim that @CodeInChaos suggested and virtualization of that directory like in Program Files folder

Comment: @evilone Why are you running your application with virtualization enabled? It's far easier to work these problems out if you stop using virtualization.

Comment: @evilone Switch off virtualization by including a `requestedExecutionLevel` entry in your app's manifest.

Comment: @evilone, still not reproduced with CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA + '\fooes\bar'. Did you try to query redirection status (SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT vs. SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT flag)?

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light No I didn't. Do you do it like this - 1. Create database with the application to the CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA\Folder|SomeFolder folder. 2. Close application 3. Delete the database 4. Run application again. In my case event restart not helped me.

Comment: @evilone, i'm anti-SQLite, so testing that with general files (data of my interest is machine-specific intermediate data collected from all users to speed-up further computations). I'm able to create and delete files from single user w/o hassle. Allowing other users to write there requires ACL adjustment. Did you check `VirtualStore` for the copy of your file?

Comment: Yes, copy is there at %AppData%\Local\VirtualStore\ProgramData\ProgramName folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard users (and that includes administrators when UAC is active) do not have delete rights to that location.

You need to find a different location to store the file if you need standard users to be able to delete it.

Comment: Where is the correct location, where all users can access the file?

Comment: @evilone Do you want all users to share a single instance of the file?

Comment: Yes, I want all users to have access to that database file

Comment: I think I would regard it as a document and locate it in a folder under [`CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA is user specific?

Comment: They **do** have write access there. Anyway, this answer presents well-known workaround instead of digging into actual problem again.

Comment: @evilone I mis-read the permissions on C:\ProgramData since they are actually a little unusual. Users can read, write and create, but they **cannot** delete which tallies with your programs inability to delete.